# My VIEW in MySQL its not working

Tags: mysql5, create-view

i play whit CREATE VIEW's in MySQL 5, now i have a troble, how can i make sure when i use this code.

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    view_shop_invoicer_list

WHERE
    accept_date >= '2009-10-16 00:00:00' AND
    accept_date <= '2009-10-31 23:59:59' AND
    shopid = [SHOPID];
```

my VIEW look like this, down here, and it will not take my accept_date into this view, is i copy/paste it from my SELECTE and insert int into my VIEW its will work, but not the order way :(

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_shop_invoicer_list;
CREATE VIEW view_shop_invoicer_list AS

SELECT
    SUM( it.transamount ) AS beloeb,
    SUM( it.cargo_fee ) AS cargo,
    SUM( 
        ( 
            it.transamount - 
            ( 
                ( it.transamount - it.cargo_fee ) / 100 * 
                ( ms.pay_adm_fee + ms.pay_marks_fee + ms.pay_kick_fee ) - 
                ( it.adm_fee + it.marketing_fee + it.kickback_fee )
            ) 
        ) 
    ) AS shop_payout,
    SUM( fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_adm_fee , it.adm_fee ) ) AS shop_adm_fee,
    SUM( fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_marks_fee , it.marketing_fee ) ) AS shop_marks_fee,
    SUM( fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_kick_fee , it.kickback_fee ) ) AS shop_kick_fee,
    it.shopid AS shopid,
    it.accept_date AS accept_date

FROM
    invoice_trans it INNER JOIN invoice i ON it.orderid = i.ordreid
    INNER JOIN shops ms ON ms.id = it.shopid

WHERE
    i.status != 0
```

i hobe sombardy know why its not working :/

## Table 1: invoice_trans

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_trans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `orderid` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '0',
  `transamount` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `transact` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `transnr` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `shopid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `accept_date` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `md5_key_declie` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `declie_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `pay_points` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `cargo_fee` int(11) NOT NULL default '4900',
  `first_time_discount` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  `adm_fee` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `marketing_fee` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `kickback_fee` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

## Table 2: invoice

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `per_fullname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `per_street` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `per_zipcode` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `per_city` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `per_email` varchar(256) NOT NULL default '',
  `fak_fullname` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `fak_street` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `fak_zipcode` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `fak_city` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `fak_email` varchar(256) NOT NULL default '',
  `push_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `splits` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dibs_ordreid` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '0',
  `reftag` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `vonchers_prices` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ordre_complate` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: I don't have any of your base tables to test against, but at first glance it seems like it should work. Maybe you can post a small but complete sql script to recreate the required tables and insert some test data? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: The problem its when i use it its take 3 ordre out, 2 for this mdr. and 1 for the last ( 16-31 - Okt ) and its ONLY shut take the 1 ordre from 16 okt to 31 okt.

Comment: Don't you need group by columns for the sum() and shop_id params?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `ordreid` (or `orderid`) column in `invoice` to join against. The script is still very much incomplete by the way, no function `fc_return_fee` or test data, so testability is very limited.

What is the error message mysql is giving you?

Comment: There its no error, the view its working current.

but i need to get the right data out, right now when i use accept_date >= '' and accept_date <= '' its will not work current.

i need to get the accept_date into my view :/ from my single select.

Comment: then you probably need to add some code to the end of your view: GROUP BY shopid, accept_date

Comment: the accept_date can be between 2009-10-16 and 2009-10-31 i don't know how i can grup by this, but yes if i can group the date's togtere its cutten be nice.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.... i fix the problem this way.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_shop_invoicer_list;
CREATE VIEW view_shop_invoicer_list AS

SELECT
    it.transamount AS beloeb,
    SUM( it.cargo_fee ) AS cargo,
    ( 
            it.transamount - 
            ( 
                ( it.transamount - it.cargo_fee ) / 100 * 
                ( ms.pay_adm_fee + ms.pay_marks_fee + ms.pay_kick_fee ) - 
                ( it.adm_fee + it.marketing_fee + it.kickback_fee )
            ) 
    ) AS shop_payout,
    fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_adm_fee , it.adm_fee ) AS shop_adm_fee,
    fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_marks_fee , it.marketing_fee ) AS shop_marks_fee,
    fc_return_fee( it.transamount , it.cargo_fee , ms.pay_kick_fee , it.kickback_fee ) AS shop_kick_fee,
    it.shopid AS shopid,
    it.accept_date AS accept_date

FROM
    invoice_trans it INNER JOIN invoice i ON it.orderid = i.ordreid

WHERE
    i.status != 0

GROUP BY
    it.id;
```

and i use this select ;) tanks for help dudes.

```
SELECT
                    SUM( beloeb ) AS beloeb,
                    SUM( cargo ) AS cargo,
                    SUM( shop_payout ) AS shop_payout,
                    SUM( shop_adm_fee ) AS shop_adm_fee,
                    SUM( shop_marks_fee ) AS shop_marks_fee,
                    SUM( shop_kick_fee ) AS shop_kick_fee,
                    accept_date,
                    shopid

                FROM
                    view_shop_invoicer_list

                WHERE
                    accept_date >= '". $this->from_date ."' AND
                    accept_date <= '". $this->to_date ."'

                GROUP BY
                    shopid
```